# Simple phase diagram using pymatgen

Tags: python, plot, pymatgen

I've been getting familiar with the pymatgen package and need to make phase diagrams. There's a quick tutorial on [this web](http://pymatgen.org/_static/Plotting%20and%20Analyzing%20a%20Phase%20Diagram%20using%20the%20Materials%20API.html) page that goes through how to make a ternary diagram, but I actually want to make a much simpler one of a pure substance.

I have in mind something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=water%20phase%20diagram&client=ubuntu&hs=IrV&sa=X&channel=fs&biw=1920&bih=995&tbm=isch&imgil=f-preTZuPSAe3M%253A%253BcwGPne-08aXjjM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww1.lsbu.ac.uk%25252Fwater%25252Fphase.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=f-preTZuPSAe3M%253A%252CcwGPne-08aXjjM%252C_&usg=__ZNKrcn6Tk5ZTur8Oqzi5yyT1jFA%3D&ved=0ahUKEwjq-uro2qnQAhVH4IMKHS8XDUgQyjcIQg&ei=NHIqWOqQA8fAjwSvrrTABA#imgrc=f-preTZuPSAe3M%3A). I've gone through the documentation and done a lot of google searches but haven;t been able to find what I'm looking for. Perhaps it's possible to combine the data from pymatgen with a graphing package like matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

T-P phase diagrams like those show phase stability against pressure and temperature as the independent variables. The data on the Materials Project was calculated using density functional theory (DFT) at a temperature of 0K and a pressure of 0Pa. Unfortunately it's not possible to create a T-P phase diagram from the MP data.